# How can I find out MAGE_RUN_CODE?

Tags: magento-1.9

In the settings I have a website and how can I find out MAGE_RUN_CODE, which I will inscribe in .htaccess?

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: You want to run  specific website from .htaccess  configuration?

Comment: I want just set 
SetEnvIf Host myUrl MAGE_RUN_CODE=goal
        SetEnvIf Host myUrl MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of MAGE_RUN_TYPE determines if MAGE_RUN_CODE should be considered the code of a website or a store. Now let’s look at Magento: a website has a code (the default websites’ code is “base”), and a store (what is actually a view, since a store can have multiple views) also has a code (the default websites’ view is “default” by default, unless you’ve changed this off course).
Now if you have a situation like I had, where you had a Magento installation with multiple websites and each multiple stores, you have different codes for both. For example, you might have the following website codes:

- site1
- site2
- site3

And the following store codes (each representing a view in a specific site):

- site1_en
- site1_nl
- site2_en
- site2_nl
- site3_en
- site3_nl

Now let’s see what happens when I try to do this:

```
Mage::run('site2_nl', 'website');
```

What you telling Magento here is to load the website with the code site2_nl . But as we see, there is no website with that code. Therefore Magento will fallback to it’s default site, or show a 404 page if it fails to do that.

Reference: https://gielberkers.com/difference-mage_run_type-website-store-magento/

Comment: You can find the store codes in the `store.code` field and the website codes in `store_website.code` field (for M2 at least).